# Common vars or how to export vars in React native app

Tags: react-native

What's the preferred way of storing common variables in a Expo.io driven React Native app? I've tried to create the following but for some reason `Vars.colors.primary` returns an error saying that `undefined is not an object`. What am I missing / How should I do this?

app/vars/Vars.js

```
var primaryColor = '#0b457e';
let tabIconDefault = '#000000';
let tabIconSelected = primaryColor;
let font_normal = 'OpenSans-Regular';
let font_bold = 'OpenSans-Bold';
let radius = 5;
let iconSize = 24;

export default {
    colors: {
        white: '#FFFFFF',
        black: '#000000',
        primary: primaryColor,
    },
    iconSize: '24'
}
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import StartScreen from 'app/screens/StartScreen'
import * as Vars from 'app/vars/Vars'

export default class AppNavigator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStack />
    );
  }
}

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        StartScreen: StartScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'StartScreen',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Vars.colors.white,
            },
            headerTintColor: Vars.colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
        },
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing `export default` you don't need to use wildcard syntax. You can just import with below statement.

```
import Vars from 'app/vars/Vars'
```

Another thing to point out; if `Vars.js` is the only file in `vars` directory you can change `Vars.js` to `index.js` and use the below syntax for more readable and more easy-to-use version.

```
import Vars from 'app/vars'
```